# Javascript only shows values and not XML information

Tags: javascript, html, xml, innerhtml

I'm makeing a manufacturing website about what types of cords are used in each country. I need it to show the information called from the XML page once the country has been selected on the dropdown menu but all I can get it to show is the value of the list item. here is my java

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
<body>

<form>
<select id="X"  onchange="myFunction ();"> 
 <option value="X">Please Choose a Country</option>

<script>

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","cords_data.xml",false);
 xmlhttp.send();
 xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 


var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Row");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
  document.write("<option value='");
  document.write(i);
 document.write("'>");
 document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Country")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  }
</script></select> <!-- <input type="submit" value="Select" onclick="go();"> -->
```

```
    <script>

 function myFunction()
 {
 var x = document.getElementById("X").selectedIndex;
 document.getElementById("feildInfo").innerHTML = x;




document.write(x[z].getElementsByTagName("Country")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); 
document.write("<br />");
document.write(x[z].getElementsByTagName("Voltage")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("<br />");
document.write(x[z].getElementsByTagName("Freq__Hz")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("<br />");
document.write(x[z].getElementsByTagName("Cord_Designator")   [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("<br />");


}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the code.  It looks like you are assigning an integer value to x, then calling getElementsByTagName on it later...  Also, can you post the HTML markup you have?

Comment: there I added all of my code and yeah I'm not understanding that part either

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your problem a bit better now.  I'll work on something.

Comment: Also, are you able / have you considered using JQuery to simplify your ajax calls?

Comment: no I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing that or where I'd start

Comment: I will use JQuery in my example, in the meantime you should check it out as it makes many things easier (though it's still good to know what's going on behind the scenes in the pure js).

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/getting-started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is what I got.

http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/eNwXn/

Basically, I re-created your form, and used JQuery for several purposes:

1. First, I create two custom JQuery events.  The first one is called when a country is selected, the second one is called when your ajax function returns with data and populates your HTML with the data.
2. Next, I add an event listener to the select list on change that triggers the event.  This is mostly done to keep the code DRY (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dont_repeat_yourself)
3. Then I create a javascript function that serves as a wrapper for the ajax call.  In this code I had to put sample data because I didn't have your actual XML file and jsfiddle does not actually allow external ajax posts.  When you try this locally, uncomment the code below (which is in the fiddle) and comment out my test code.

The basic idea is: When the user selects a country, load the data.  You can filter the data using the selected country and then display it on the page.

```
//Uncomment these lines in your code
$.ajax({
    url: "cords_data.xml"
        , cache: false
        , type: "get"
        , data: null
}).done(function (xmlData) {
    if (xmlData != undefined && xmlData != null) { // make sure we got data back
        $(document).trigger("display-cord-data", xmlData);
    } else {
        console.log("No data returned.");
        alert("An error occurred while loading data.");
    } // end if/else
}).fail(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
        alert("BOOOM");
});
```

As a starting point on how to parse XML using JQuery, see this link:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/

Also, here are some ways to target nodes in your XML document
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: thank you so much! So where exactly should I put this in my code or should I just take my script out? Also do I have to add any other information to this or do I leave it as is?

Comment: Essentially, you can use all of the script in the JS fiddle (and uncomment the lines matching the ones above that are commented out.  You can also comment out the test code I added.  You can also adapt the JQuery selectors I used to target my html markup (like .content and .header) to match whatever your needs are.